# Rewriting Python SHA1 Digest code to Bash

Tags: python, bash, hash, sha1, openwrt

On Debian machines I run the following Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

text_in = "abcd".encode('utf8')

sha1 = hashlib.sha1()
sha1.update(text_in)
raw_digest = sha1.digest()
text_out = base64.b64encode(raw_digest)

print( "text_in: " + str(text_in) )
print( "text_out: " + str(text_out) )
```

Below is the result of Python code:

```
text_in: abcd
text_out: gf6L/odXbD7LIkJvjleEc4KRes8=
```

It's TRUE.

I'm trying to rewrite this Python code to Bash code:

```
#!/bin/sh

TEXT_IN="abcd"

DIGEST=$( echo -n "$TEXT_IN" | sha1sum | awk '{print $1}' )
TEXT_OUT=$( echo -n "$DIGEST" | base64 )

echo "TEXT_IN: $TEXT_IN"
echo "TEXT_OUT: $TEXT_OUT"
```

Below is the result of my Bash code:

```
TEXT_IN: abcd
TEXT_OUT: ODFmZThiZmU4NzU3NmMzZWNiMjI0MjZmOGU1Nzg0NzM4MjkxN2FjZg==
```

It's FALSE.

I need to run this Bash code in OpenWRT which is low on disk space and uses easy code in scripts, lightweight software and simple solutions.

Please help me rewrite this code from Python to Bash.

Answer (score 2):

Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean (except for a spurious warning about using a variable in the `printf` format string) Bash code:

```
#!/bin/bash -p

text_in='abcd'

printf_fmt=$(printf '%s' "$text_in" | sha1sum  \
                | sed -e 's/[[:space:]].*$//' -e 's/../\\x&/g')
text_out=$(printf "$printf_fmt" | base64)

printf 'text_in: %s\n' "$text_in"
printf 'text_out: %s\n' "$text_out"
```

- See [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/673055/4154375) for an explanation of why the code does not use ALL_UPPERCASE variable names.
- See the accepted, and excellent, answer to [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/264812) for an explanation of why the code uses `printf` everywhere instead of `echo`.
- Note that you have tagged the question with `bash` but presented `sh` code.  They are different.  See [Difference between sh and Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5725296/4154375).  The code above may not work with `sh` instead of `bash` because the `printf` in some `sh` implementations does not support `\x` in format strings.

Comment: Please include an explanation of why the OPs code doesn't work. There is a comment below the question that has this information.